# How to access my dev laptop mvc site from my ipod touch on same wireless network?

Tags: model-view-controller, iis

I'm running vista business with IIS 7. Here is what I want to do and can't figure it out. Have tried all kinds of permutations, but I'm missing something and could really use the help.

I'm on a home wireless network. My laptop, which is my dev machine has an IP of 192.168.1.102. I'm writing a mobile site using MVC beta 4 (but should be same configuration as MVC 3) and have an ipod touch 4g which from a mobile site standpoint is identical to an iphone 4.

What I want to do is be able to navigate to the site from my ipod touch thats running on my dev laptop. When I navigate to the aforementioned IP address, I get the IIS 7 home page. So that's the good news. I can get to it from the ipod. (both are on the same wireless network) However, I don't want the default IIS site. I want to see my mobile site. However, I don't want it as a virtual site. (I don't want 192.168.1.102/mysite) I want to navigate to 192.168.1.102 and have it go right to my mobile site rather than the default IIS 7 site.

Here's what I have done:

1. Created a new website under IIS 7 with port 80. I intend to use host headers.
2. Added a host header and also added 127.0.0.1 www.test.com to the hosts file

On my dev laptop, I can navigate directly to www.test.com and it works fine. However, when I use the ipod touch and navigate to 192.168.1.102 I still get the default IIS 7 site.

How can I configure my dev laptop so that from my ipod touch I can navigate to 192.168.1.102 and it displays the home page of my site? Is this possible?

Thank you kindly in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm being foolish and not fully understanding your question properly, but why don't you just move your web application outside of your folder and put it in the root directory? Isn't that what you're trying to do?

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. However, I should of made it clear that I do need the default web site also as it is running my source control, etc.

Comment: What I want to do is leave the default site as is and add another site that I can directly navigate to. I hope this is possible.